# Sqlserver query with Laravel DB class runs extremly slow

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, apache2

I have:

- Laravel 10.13.5
- apache2
- ubuntu 22-04
- PHP 8.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun 8 2023 15:27:40) (NTS)

When I execute this query via the DB facade:

```php
$data = DB::connection('sqlsrv')
    ->select('select * from my_table')
```

It takes more than one minute to return data.

When I do the same query using `php_pdo_sqlsrv`:

```php
$serverName = "XX.XX.XXX.XX\INSTANCE, 1433"; 

$connectionInfo = ["Database"=>"my_database", "UID"=>"my_user", "PWD"=>"my_pwd"];

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

It takes less than 5 seconds.

When I execute this project on my local machine, I don't have any problems with the DB facade.

I work with Windows, XAMPP, and I use ODBC `sqlserver` to make the connection.

What could the issue be? Maybe `apache2`? The version of Laravel DB Class?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `sqlsrv_` functions are not using PDO. Can you test again using PDO version of PHP Driver for SQL Server ( I think Laravel uses PDO for database connections and data manipulations)? Something like: `$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd); $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table"); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: First of all, the DB Laravel facade has nothing to do with it working or not, and the Laravel Facade version cannot be changed, if you are using Laravel 10, you will have every Facade to be "laravel 10 version", etc. Second, when you do not use the Facade, are you also executing the code in the server? You need to add more debugging info